# What is the convention of __ means in php?

Tags: php, naming-conventions

I saw some ppl write code like this:

They use __ in the naming of a variable:

```
   public static function getInstance(){
        if(self::$__instance == NULL) self::$__instance = new SCFormatter();
        return self::$__instance;
    }
```

not only variable, but also the function:

```
   private function __clone(){}
```

Is there any special meaning for php coder to use "__" as a prefix. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`__` in `PHP` is for [`magic methods`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) like `__get`, `__set`, `__clone`

Historically `_` before variable or function means it's private since there was no private, public or protected methods in `PHP 4`.

It is applied not only to `PHP`. In `Python` for example, `_` prefix for functions and variables is used for the same purpose.

I suggest to **avoid naming your functions prefixing them with `__`** (double underscore) since PHP developers can add the same magic function in next versions of the language, so it would break your code. You can use one underscore still - it is not dangerous, since it can't affect the language features.
Although it's possible, please notice that using `_` for property / method name prefix is not advised since it doesn't comply with most of the coding standards nowadays.

Answer (score 8):

There's no special syntactic meaning. However, it's *highly* discouraged by the PHP team to use `__` at the beginning of names, because you might break future core PHP features.

PHP tries to prefix core names with `__` so they don't interfere with your names. For example, there's a `__construct()` method, a `__sleep()` method, a `__wakeup()` method, etc. They didn't call them `construct()`, `sleep()` and `wakeup()` because they might interfere with your own names.

This is a general practice. Same in the Linux kernel for example. System functions are prefixed with `__` so they don't interfere with your naming. If you start prefixing your own names with `__`, then you'll start interfering with *their* naming, which will either break system functions or most likely your application in the future, when you least expect it.

If the PHP team somehow decides to create a static variable in each class with the name `$__instance`, then all your scripts will start breaking suddenly and you won't know why.

Quoting the caution in the PHP manual page for [Magic Methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php):

> PHP reserves all function names starting with `__` as magical. It is recommended that you do not use function names with `__` in PHP unless you want some documented magic functionality.

And about [`__clone()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) — it's a PHP feature, going farther to demonstrate that prefixing your own names with `__` can be pretty confusing as well.

Answer (score 4):

All the [PHP Magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) begin with a double underscore. This includes `__clone()`. Although it's not enforced by PHP, naming your own methods starting with a double underscore is discouraged as these names may collide with future PHP magic methods.

Answer (score 1):

They are typically there to symbolize private variables.  Basically variables and methods can't have the same name so its there to provide private variables with no conflicting names.  I would just use a single underscore if you going that route.

Also as mentioned other places php has magic methods.